# Ubuntu and Django, no module named 'django'

Tags: 14.04, command-line, python, lts

I have a problem with Django on Ubuntu. When I type `python` in terminal, terminal returns

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, Jun  2 2015, 15:13:43) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
```

so it's allright.

When I type `admin-django.py version`, terminal returns

```
1.8.2
```

so it's still allright.

But when I go with `python` > `import django` terminal returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I'm fighting with it whole day, I'm quite new to linux. Do you know any solution?

SOLVED: `sudo pip3 install Django` solved whole issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try reinstall Django, these are the ways to reinstall:

`sudo pip uninstall Django`

`sudo pip install Django==1.8.2`

More information, check the official webpage:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/

Comment: I used pip install Django==1.8.2, that's the point....

Comment: try `>>> import django`
`>>> print(django.get_version())`. this need return the django version. Case return error, you need reinstall the framework.

Comment: Would you tell me how to completely remove django?

Comment: This occurred with me too. Just worked when I reinstalled the framework

Comment: How to remove: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/#removing-old-versions-of-django

Comment: I updated the answer with this information.

Comment: @letsdisappear Any update?

Comment: `sudo pip3 install Django` solved everything, thank you for help